# Некорректная работа цикла или моя ошибка

Tags: python, циклы, python-3.5

Есть массив чисел:

```
cen_x = [770.5, 867.5, 1164.0, 312.0, 1256.0]
```

Пишу такой цикл:

```
kat_x = []
for i in range(len(cen_x)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cen_x)):
        k_x = abs(cen_x[i] - cen_x[i + 1])
        kat_x.append(k_x)
print(kat_x)
```

По-идее в `kat_x` должно быть 10 разных чисел, но получается такой результат:

```
[97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 296.5, 296.5, 296.5, 852.0, 852.0, 944.0]
```

Не знаю в чем дело.

Comment: интересно назвали заголовок вопроса :) мне кажется, или это одно и то же?

Comment: Cогласен. Корректнее было бы назвать "Некорректная работа цикла из-за моей ошибки", но я без понятия в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: чтобы вопрос был более полезным, словами нужно указать, что вы ожидаете ваш код должен сделать (это может помочь лучше решение предложить и может помочь другим людям с похожей задачей найти вопрос). Не нужно сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи использовать. Например, я сперва подумал что вы хотите `[abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(cen_x, cen_x[1:])]` сделать, но принятый вами ответ от @Vlad from Moscow другое делает. Вы можете обновить вопрос (особенно заголовок) и привести явно ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хотя я не знаю Python, но, похоже, должно быть

```
kat_x = []
for i in range(len(cen_x)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cen_x)):
        k_x = abs(cen_x[i] - cen_x[j])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          
        kat_x.append(k_x)
print(kat_x)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибку вам уже нашли, а я добавлю только, что то, как вы пытаетесь решить задачу - это очень не по-питоновски.

В питоне мы стараемся не перебирать в цикле элементы по индексам. Цикл for позволяет перебирать элементы непосредственно. Так получается гораздо нагляднее и снижает вероятность ошибок.

Если же в каком-то частном случае вместе с элементом нужен и его индекс (например, как в вашем случае - чтобы использования его, чтобы ограничить вложенный цикл), то можно с помощью функции enumerate получать пары (индекс, значение).

```
cen_x = [770.5, 867.5, 1164.0, 312.0, 1256.0]

kat_x = []
for i, x1 in enumerate(cen_x):
    for x2 in cen_x[i+1:]:
        k_x = abs(x1 - x2)
        kat_x.append(k_x)

print(kat_x)
```

Так читается попроще, чем в вашем случае. В питоне очень большое значение уделяется читабильности кода, потому что читать код приходится в разы больше, чем писать его.

Но, на самом деле, вашу задачу можно решить ещё проще.

Циклами вы пытаетесь найти все комбинации двух элементов. Но для этого в питоне существует готовая функция (в питоне вообще очень много уже готовых функций).

```
from itertools import combinations


cen_x = [770.5, 867.5, 1164.0, 312.0, 1256.0]

pairs = combinations(cen_x, 2)
kat_x = [abs(p[0] - p[1]) for p in pairs]

print(kat_x)
```

Крайне рекомендую познакомиться с модулем itertools и с другими существующими библиотеками питона - как встроенными, так и сторонними.

Их для питона не просто много, а ОЧЕНЬ много - на все случаи жизни. И часто можно не изобретать свой велосипед, а написать в поисковике *"python модуль %ключевые_слова_вашей_задачи%"*